# Throwing a error message if the user id not exist in mysql using node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Right now, in my code, if I input an id, which is not present in the database, it's showing empty array on the console. But rather than empty array, I want to print an error message. This is my code.

```
 server.on('request', (req, res) => {
        case '/get':
        req.on('end', () => {   
            let id = reqUrl.query.id;                      
            let sql = `Select * from students  WHERE id= ${id} `; 

            con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(result);
                });
                })
            res.end('');  
 });
```

**this console.log(result)** shows `[ RowDataPacket { id: 3, name: 'v', grade: 1 } ]` if an id exists but if an id is not present then it shows **[ ]**. But instead of **[ ]**, i want to show a message like **id doesn't exist**

Comment: why throw error.. you have to catch that exception

Comment: or you can simple console error and return like `if (err) console.log("id does not exist");  return;`

Comment: @AneesIjaz but it's not showing any kind of error. Even, if i write this cond. it still returns `[ ]`

Comment: console the error without the condition ? what's the output

Comment: output is `[]` if the id doesn't exist. It's always going to the else statement.

Comment: put `console.log(error);` right after the start of the function. like `con.query(sql, function (err, result) { console.log(error) ...`

Comment: it's showing error is `null`

Comment: sorry .. node js returns empty array of result if there is no any result... you can apply check `if(result.length <= 0) console.log('id does not exist')`

Comment: yah done by using `!result.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply a check if result length is 0 then console message

```
 server.on('request', (req, res) => {
    case '/get':
    req.on('end', () => {   
        let id = reqUrl.query.id;                      
        let sql = `Select * from students  WHERE id= ${id} `; 
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if(result.length)
                console.log("Found");
            else
                console.log("id not found");
        });
    })
    res.end('');  
 });
```